# How to Hardware accelerate compose views on Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is there an already existing api for enabling Hardware Acceleration on jetpack compose? Note: I don't mean on app level or activity level, what I'm asking for is for the widget level.

Comment: It should already use hardware acceleration, as that has been the default for years.

Comment: Then, why is that when I enabled hardware acceleration on the app level, I notice performance improvement compared to when acceleration tag is not there

Comment: "what I'm asking for is for the widget level" -- there is no "widget level". From the OS standpoint, the entire Compose-rendered UI is a single `View`. "why is that when I enabled hardware acceleration on the app level, I notice performance improvement compared to when acceleration tag is not there" -- I suggest that you create a sample project that reproduces your findings, then file an issue in the issue tracker, where you explain in detail your approach for "notice performance improvement", so the Compose team can try to reproduce your findings.